# Call to undefined method error when using Singleton in PHP

Tags: php

I have a project where I use aws sdk for php. Here I am trying to create S3Client with singleton. But it does not create S3Client outside of the constructor.

Here is the class:

```
class ClientController
{

private static $client;

private function __construct()
{
    try {
        self::$client = new S3Client([
            'region' => AWS_S3_REGION,
            'version' => AWS_S3_VERSION,
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => AWS_S3_KEY,
                'secret' => AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY
            ],
        ]);
        echo 'test3333333333';
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        //logging
    }
}

public static function s3Client()
{
    if(!isset(self::$client)) {
        echo 'test1';
        self::$client = new ClientController();
    }
    echo 'test2';
    return self::$client;
}

}
```

And index file I run in another folder:

```
var_dump(ClientController::s3Client()->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'jetdeneme',
    'Key' => $request,
)));
```

Output:

```
test1test3333333333test2
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ClientController::getObject() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cdn\index.php:10
```

When I use the above var_dump in ClientController's constructor, it doesn't give an error. But it gives outside of the constructor. I just want to create and use the Client using the static function.

Comment: What type do you expect `$client` to be? In your constructor you are setting it to an instance of `S3Client`, but in your `s3Client` method you are setting it to an instance of `ClientController`. Also, generally don't bother try/catching in a constructor (unless you are protecting secrets). It is usually better to `try` the thing that invokes your constructor itself. And during development, it is often better to not `try` anything so that you can better see errors.

Comment: I want to use $client for S3Client's methods. Isn't the point of a singleton anyway to create it only once and access it in a similar way to private? For example, we can make a database connection and use its functions to run its queries. I tried checking instanceof etc. but it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes, the point of a singleton is to only create something once. My point is that you are calling `self::$client = new` twice, which is a code-smell for a singleton. You are also setting the property to two different things, so what is your singleton supposed to represent, the `ClientController` or the `S3Client`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that you can build a singleton. I've included a mock S3Client just for demo purposes. A common pattern in singletons is to use a private constructor and a `getInstance()` method, the latter setting the single instance on first invocation and then returning it. Once inside of the singleton, we're back to standard OOP so we have instance methods and properties including `getClient()` which also stores an instance of the client.

```php
<?php

class S3Client
{
    public function getObject()
    {
        return 'Inside client';
    }
}

class ClientController
{
    private static self $instance;

    private ?S3Client $client = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    public function getClient(): S3Client
    {
        // Lazy invocation, could be moved to constructor, too
        if (!$this->client) {
            $this->client = new S3Client();
        }

        return $this->client;
    }

    public static function getInstance(): self
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

var_dump(ClientController::getInstance()->getClient());
var_dump(ClientController::getInstance()->getClient());
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/oK6re

If instead you want your singleton to only represent the instance of the S3Client you could do something like this:

```php
class S3Helper
{
    private static ?S3Client $instance = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
        // NOOP
    }

    public static function getClient(): S3Client
    {
        // Lazy invocation, could be moved to constructor, too
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new S3Client();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

var_dump(S3Helper::getClient());
var_dump(S3Helper::getClient());
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/k3udc

The first pattern would usually be used if `ClientController` has other things that it could return besides the S3Client, but if that's the only thing it does, then the second pattern might make more sense.

I'll also add that the name of class really should make it obvious what it does and how it should be used. Personally I'm not certain that `ClientController` is a good name for a thing that holds an instance of an API helper. I'm not saying `S3Helper` is the greatest, either, but I think it is a little more obvious in what it does.